# Where is the checkbox to disable the middle button of my touchpad?

Tags: debian, gnome, touchpad

This is Debian 9. I've not had this functionality before, maybe because I've always used touchpads with separate buttons. Now on a buttonless touchpad there's the middle button feature, which keeps closing my browser tabs, among other strange helpful tricks it plays. I've searched for the option that turns this off, but couldn't find it either in the "All Settings" nor through the Tweak Tool. The Internet is rather mute about this, or I don't know how to ask. Is the checkbox/switch there at all? Where is it then? Or what's the CLI method?

```
# dmesg | grep -i touch
[    1.583544] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x126800/0x0, board id: 2910, fw id: 1552988
[    1.615908] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input2
```

Xorg.0.log:

```
# grep -i touch /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[    13.689] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event1)
[    13.689] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[    13.689] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[    13.691] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[    13.691] (II) input device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[    13.691] (II) input device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad', /dev/input/event1 is a touchpad
[    13.691] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 13)
[    13.691] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    13.691] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    13.691] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    13.692] (II) input device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[    13.692] (II) input device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad', /dev/input/event1 is a touchpad
[    13.693] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse0)
```

Comment: What kind of touchpad?

Comment: @MichaelHomer It's in Fujitsu Lifebook A544. I don't know how to check it.

Comment: I don't either, but `lspci` or `dmesg` or `Xorg.0.log` might at least give you a hint of what it is or at least what driver's being used. Either way, [edit] in the machine and perhaps somebody who knows about them will see it.

Comment: @MichaelHomer It's Synaptics, if I'm not wrong. Logs included above.

Comment: check out the man pages `synaptics(4)` which describes the features, and `synclient(1)` which allows you try things out.  Then `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` or similar shows what you might edit in your `Xorg.conf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was enough to install `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` to stop the middle button feature. A reboot was required. (Maybe there's another, softer way to apply the changes.) The installation disabled some of the options available through "All Settings" in Gnome like edge scrolling. These are the options right after installation:

```
$ synclient -l
Parameter settings:
LeftEdge                = 1668
RightEdge               = 5354
TopEdge                 = 1516
BottomEdge              = 4440
FingerLow               = 25
FingerHigh              = 30
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 240
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = 109
HorizScrollDelta        = 109
VertEdgeScroll          = 0
HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.0365631
TouchpadOff             = 0
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 0
RBCornerButton          = 0
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 0
TapButton2              = 0
TapButton3              = 0
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 3
ClickFinger3            = 2
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 0
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 0
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 27
VertHysteresis          = 27
ClickPad                = 1
RightButtonAreaLeft     = 3511
RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
RightButtonAreaTop      = 4066
RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

The settings seem to reside in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf`.

Configuration adjustments can be written to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` or in the directory `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`. (A reboot is needed apparently. Maybe there's another way...)